# Indexing dbpedia datasets onto elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, rdf, dbpedia

I'm working on a university project for a chatbot that answers various questions based on dbpedia's RDF datasets.
At the moment, the chatbot is very specific and is able to answer questions related to the subdomain of Marvel movies. My goal is to generalize, in particular by indexing the dbpedia content using elasticsearch, and then trying to make queries using these indexes.

However, I don't know elasticsearch and I've never worked on indexing. In particular, I'm having a hard time understanding how to preprocess dbpedia datasets and then how to think about indexing. I would like some advice on the strategy to follow.

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"However, I don't know elasticsearch and I've never worked on indexing."* - well, and now? Shouldn't you read about ElasticSearch then first? It's also not clear what part of the DBpedia dataset you want to index nor what kind of queries you want to run on the index. I mean, it's a text index, so obviously, you should index the textual data. Lots of people including my research group indexed DBpedia data via Lucene. But just the entities and not the relations. So why do you want to use ElasticSearch at all? The RDF data is indexed in triple stores and SPARQL is the query language for RDF

Comment: By the way, your question is clearly to broad ...

Comment: @AKSW Hi, I try to be more specific now. I think I should use elasticsearch to index the entities from dbpedia, and use these indexes to perform named entity linking and / or named entity recognition, so as to recognize the dbpedia entities in the user question. I would like to know how I should set the index structure in this case, i.e. for example the various fields and properties that each json document in the index should have.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch gives you a platform to search and store the data. This is not meaning that you can user Elasticsearch only to fetch or read data from somewhere. In fact, you need to search on Elastic Stack.

[image]

For more information, in this image, your data on the right side, client-server. You need to use some scripts or Elastic Stack products like logstash, filebeat, etc. to fetch data from source to Elasticsearch. After that, you understand your data structure exactly to make your search fast. For the first time, Elasticsearch will handle all the data structure issues like mapping but this can make your searches a bit slow. You need to [change your mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html). So you need to read some documentation. After sending the data to Elasticsearch, you can visualize the data with Kibana. For more specialized questions, first, go to [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html), if you can not find there or understand go back here.

Also, please check the graph capability of Elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/elasticon/conf/2016/sf/graph-capabilities-in-the-elastic-stack

it is suitable for the DBpedia or not.

Edit: After researching a bit more, I found something really good things about. Here the links :

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/indexing-rdf-datasets/84281/6
- https://gist.github.com/markharwood/21c723039425b4b3e4277b2bffa5c54c (this is a python script for indexing the Elasticsearch.)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzWT-2xdaek&feature=youtu.be (Also video)